# Whats the expressive way of or'ing a range of bools?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

I recently came across a situation where i needed to 'or' a range of bools together.

An example could be `std::vector<bool> bools;`

I have come up with some different ways of or'ing all of them together:

```
std::any_of(bools.begin(), bools.end(), [](bool x) { return x; } )
```

*or*

```
std::find(bools.begin(), bools.end(), true) != bools.end()
```

*or*

```
std::accumulate(bools.begin(), bools.end(), false, std::logical_or);
```

*or*

```
std::accumulate(bools.begin(), bools.end(), 0) != 0;
```

If the length is fixed, I could use a `std::bitset` which has the `any` function - but this is only an option in that case.

Of all these, neither is very intuitive or is really expressing the intent clearly here (in a small way they all exhibit some kind of "WTF? code")

The irony with this situation is that for [variadic-templates](/questions/tagged/variadic-templates) we do have the [fold-expression](/questions/tagged/fold-expression)s which, in comparison, would be simple and expressive:

```
(bools || ...)
```

*Note*: I do have [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) which have the range library, but AFAIK it doesn't alleviate this issue really.

Comment: Personally I would just put `std::find(bools.begin(), bools.end(), true) != bools.end()` inside a named function.  The code in the function is easy to understand if you ever need to open it up, and having a good name should mean you never have to.

Comment: `std::accumulate` has to traverse the whole range, the others are fine i would say

Comment: It should be one of the first two because they short-circuit while `accumulate` doesn't. In c++20 you'll probably have `std::identity` which can replace the lambda.

Comment: Isn't this one of those times that putting a nice loop in a nice function is the easiest, clearest and simplest way to go? Why complicate things? `template <typename It> bool AnyAreTrue(It begin, It end) { for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) { if (*it) return true; } return false; }`

Comment: `An example could be std::vector<bool> bools;` another example would be using an integer and doing bitwise operations on it - then oring the lot of them is easy `if (!fields) { //all are 0}`

Comment: @UKMonkey imho that an obfuscation rather than adding expressivness, and now I realize why the question is primarily opinion based ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I'd like to say I was playing the devils advocate ... but advocate is a strong word. ^_^